# Shouldn't Pain's head have melted off during the fight with Naruto as 9-tails?

Tags: naruto

When Naruto and Pains were fighting, Naruto turned into Naruto's six-tailed version 2 form and he held Pain's head. As we saw with Orochimaru's fight, his snake melted off when he touched Naruto.

Why didn't he at least get a burn?

Comment: Because he's pain. That's why he didn't get burned. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably just because Pain needed to appear stronger than Orochimaru, but we can try to make it work.
First we should note that it wasn't Orochimaru's body that touched Naruto, but his snake. Which we can try to understand as being a product of some jutsu, not just a flesh-and-bone snake. Orochimaru could just be so good at chakra shape transformation that he could give an actual physical appearance to his chakra, and not just a generic shape like in most jutsu, and the plot does give him this level of talent.

Now, with Pain, we know that the Rinnegan has some very strong chakra absortion and manipulation techniques, and the fact that the bodies weren't really alive, but rather being controlled remotely, could reduce the "rotting" and "melting" effect, after all, Naruto is touching dirt, grass and rocks and none of those are melting on contact.

Answer (score 1):

Although it isn't stated exactly why the 9 tails chakra didn't affect Pain. I have 2 possible reasons.

The first would be because of the Rinnengan. We both Know that all the Deva paths of Pain had been defeated before Naruto entered the tailed beast versions (So Nagato could use the abilities of all the other 6 paths) . Due to that, Nagato was able to focus more on his fight with Naruto and when Naruto held his head, he probably absorbed some of the chakra using the absorption path of the rinnengan.

Another reason could be because of the exact state of the tailed beast chakra. When Naruto was fighting Orochimaru, he was in the 4 tailed chakra cloak but while he was fighting Pain, he started at the 5 tails and past that point, the chakra is cloaked in skeleton and skin. it could be that past the 5 tails, the chakra becomes more coated and the person gets closer to appearing like the actual Jinchuuriki. So Pain Probably didn't get in contact with as much pure chakra as Orochimaru did.

Hope that helped in  a way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because orochimaru had infused himself with other's blood, making him basically a patchwork of chakra. When naruto grabbed him he melted the bonds between the chakras. Pain had a chakra that can from several points on his body (the metal rods), and thus by grabbing a part, naruto could not destroy the chakra there, since it was still flowing in.